# JNI, how to access a correct instance of object in native code

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I try to create two objects in java which creating objects in native code and accessing their values.

Java code:

MyObject.java

```
package com.myobject;

public class MyObject {
    
    public native void setId(int id); 
    public native int getId(); 

    public MyObject() {
        System.load("C:\\...MyObjects.dll");
    }
}
```

TestObjects.java

```
package com.myobject;

import com.myobject.MyObject;

public class TestObjects {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        MyObject obj1 = new MyObject();
        
        obj1.setId(1);

        System.out.println("obj1 id="+obj1.getId());
        
        MyObject obj2 = new MyObject();
        
        obj2.setId(2);
        
        System.out.println("obj1 id="+obj1.getId());
        System.out.println("obj2 id="+obj2.getId());
        
    }    
}
```

c++ code:

com_myobject_MyObject.h

```
#include <jni.h>

#ifndef _Included_com_myobject_MyObject
#define _Included_com_myobject_MyObject
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_myobject_MyObject
 * Method:    setId
 * Signature: (I)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_myobject_MyObject_setId
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint);

/*
 * Class:     com_myobject_MyObject
 * Method:    getId
 * Signature: ()I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_myobject_MyObject_getId
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Source.cpp

```
#include "com_myobject_MyObject.h"
#include "MyClass.h"

MyObject* myObject = NULL;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_myobject_MyObject_setId
(JNIEnv*, jobject, jint id) {

    myObject = new MyObject();

    myObject->setId(id);
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_myobject_MyObject_getId
(JNIEnv*, jobject) {
    
    if (myObject != NULL)
        return myObject->getId();
    else
        return -1;
}
```

MyClass.cpp

```
#include "MyClass.h"

MyObject::MyObject() {
    id = 0;
}

int MyObject::getId() {
    return id;
}

void MyObject::setId(int newId) {
    id = newId;
}
```

MyClass.h

```
#pragma once

class MyObject
{
private:

    int id;
    
public:

    MyObject();

    int getId();
    void setId(int);

};
```

But as the result both java objects return the value from the same object:

```
obj1 id=1
obj1 id=2
obj2 id=2
```

How can I create a unique instance of object in c++ code which will correspond to each java objects, so as the result it should be:

```
obj1 id=1
obj1 id=1
obj2 id=2
```

Answer (score 0):

In Source.cpp:

- when setId is called, you instantiate a MyObject, store it in a global variable, and set the id.
- when getId is called, you get the id of the latest instantiated MyObject

So I guess your mistake is using a global variable which can store only one instance, the latest.

Answer (score 0):

I've found one of the solutions is using a pointer to C++ object in java object:

Java code:

MyObject.java

```
package com.myobject;

public class MyObject {
    
    public native long init();
    public native void setId(int id, long ptr); 
    public native int getId(long ptr); 

    public MyObject() {
        System.load("C:\\...MyObjects.dll");
    }
}
```

TestObjects.java

```
package com.myobject;

import com.myobject.MyObject;

public class TestObjects {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        MyObject obj1 = new MyObject();
        
        long lObj1 = obj1.init();
        
        obj1.setId(1, lObj1);

        System.out.println("obj1 id="+obj1.getId(lObj1));
        
        MyObject obj2 = new MyObject();
        
        long lObj2 = obj2.init();
        
        obj2.setId(2, lObj2);
        
        System.out.println("obj1 id="+obj1.getId(lObj1));
        System.out.println("obj2 id="+obj2.getId(lObj2));
        
    }    
}
```

c++ code:

com_myobject_MyObject.h

```
#include <jni.h>

#ifndef _Included_com_myobject_MyObject
#define _Included_com_myobject_MyObject
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    /*
     * Class:     com_myobject_MyObject
     * Method:    init
     * Signature: ()J
     */
    JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_myobject_MyObject_init
    (JNIEnv*, jobject);

    /*
     * Class:     com_myobject_MyObject
     * Method:    setId
     * Signature: (IJ)V
     */
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_myobject_MyObject_setId
    (JNIEnv*, jobject, jint, jlong);

    /*
     * Class:     com_myobject_MyObject
     * Method:    getId
     * Signature: (J)I
     */
    JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_myobject_MyObject_getId
    (JNIEnv*, jobject, jlong);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Source.cpp

```
#include "com_myobject_MyObject.h"
#include "MyClass.h"


MyObject* myObject = NULL;

JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_myobject_MyObject_init
(JNIEnv*, jobject) {
    myObject = new MyObject();
    return (long)myObject;
}

/*
 * Class:     com_myobject_MyObject
 * Method:    setId
 * Signature: (IJ)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_myobject_MyObject_setId
(JNIEnv*, jobject, jint id, jlong ptr) {

    MyObject* pObject = (MyObject*)ptr;

    pObject->setId(id);
}

/*
 * Class:     com_myobject_MyObject
 * Method:    getId
 * Signature: (J)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_myobject_MyObject_getId
(JNIEnv*, jobject, jlong ptr) {

    MyObject* pObject = (MyObject*)ptr;

    if (pObject != NULL)
        return pObject->getId();
    else
        return -1;

}
```

Result is:

```
obj1 id=1
obj1 id=1
obj2 id=2
```